# Get rsync to list ignored files in verbose output

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to get `rsync` to list all the files ignored/excluded in transfer, in addition to the files transferred?

Comment: Can you [provide an example scenario](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/608976/edit), please, including the command(s) you've tried. It would help so as not to repeat something you've already discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `-vv`

```
$ rsync -rvv test/a/ test/b/ --exclude '/files/a*'
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding file files/all because of pattern /files/a*
...
```

Comment: `rsync --exclude 'somedir/' ...` will not list files inside that `somedir` directory, because it's the directory itself that has been excluded